# Error: Request to googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token Failed When Using Google Spreadsheet npm Package with VPN in China (Works Fine in Morocco)

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, next.js, google-api, google-oauth

I'm currently working on a project where I need to access Google Sheets using the google-spreadsheet npm package. Due to restrictions, I'm based in China and using a VPN to access Google services. However, I'm encountering an issue where I'm getting the following error `Error: Request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason:` 
Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
import { JWT } from "google-auth-library";
import { GoogleSpreadsheet} from "google-spreadsheet";

const serviceAccountAuth = new JWT({
  email: creds.client_email,
  key: creds.private_key,
  scopes: SCOPES,
});


const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(googleSheetId, serviceAccountAuth);
```

I suspect this error is due to the VPN and possibly related to Google's restrictions in China. How can I resolve this issue and successfully authenticate with Google's OAuth2 service while using a VPN in China? Any insights or workaround suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Note: I've tested this code with a friend located in Morocco, and it works fine on their laptop without any issues.

Comment: It seems your code isn't using the proxy at all and being blocked.

Comment: can you test with official library ('google-spreadsheet` is not official), here is example [code](https://pastebin.com/sEbaa5Xb) that appends row to a sheet.

Comment: @bogdanoff I have tried using googleapis but same error.

Comment: can you verify that your requests are going through VPN ? like try to get your ip addr using fetch/axios or just curl to `https://ip.me` website.

Comment: import {HttpsProxyAgent} from 'https-proxy-agent'
import {google} from 'googleapis'

google.options({agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://135.125.56.179:25165')})


I have a lead to this to use a proxy like this but I am really new to this I don't know what to put write in HttpsProxyAgent.

Comment: @AbdullahRehmani You can set proxy thougn environment variable as shown [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/97a1b6c8896e8449442a0a840f46bb9a92cef060?tab=readme-ov-file#using-a-proxy).
put that in .env file if you have or just run (eg) `HTTPS_PROXY="https://<ip>:<port>" node ./main.js`